# Bot auto responds to only one dm

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so I am trying to get a bot to answer to dm sent. However I want it to only reply to a person once regardless of the amount of messages sent.
Here is my code so far.

Note: I put the timeout function on purpose, I want it to have a 5 second wait period.

```js
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (message.channel.type == "dm") {
      message.author.send("Hi");
    }
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const users = new Set();
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
   if (users.has(message.author.id)) return; // if user has already sent dm
   message.author.send('Hi');
   users.add(message.author.id); // if not, add user to the set and send the message
  }
 }, 5000);
});
```